# How to correctly set root for nginx server?

Tags: nginx

I must set `root` in server, not in `location`. If I set it this way:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root   /opt/html;
        index  index_sc.html;
    }

    location /imgproxy/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
}
```

Then I can access `/imgproxy` content without problem. But if I move the `root` out of `location` like below, `/imgproxy` will cause `404` error:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.mydomain.com;
    root   /opt/html;

    location / {
        index  index_sc.html;
    }

    location /imgproxy/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
}
```

I want to know how exactly can I set `root` in `server` and still has `location /imgproxy/` work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this behaviour, but you can explicitly handle the `/imgproxy` URI by adding another [`location` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

```
root   /opt/html;

location / {
    index  index_sc.html;
}

location = /imgproxy {
    return 301 /imgproxy/;
}

location /imgproxy/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

Ensure that you clear the browser cache between changes to the `nginx` configuration.